# Hive - Is there a way to dynamically create tables from a list

Tags: hive

I'm using Hive to aggregate stats, and I want to do a breakdown by the industry our customers fall under. Ideally, I'd like to write the stats for each industry to a separate output file per industry (e.g. industry1_stats, industry2_stats, etc.). I have a list of various industries our customers are in, but that list isn't pre-set.

So far, everything I've seen from Hive documentation indicates that I need to know what tables I'd want beforehand and hard-code those into my Hive script. Is there a way to do this dynamically, either in the Hive script itself (preferable) or through some external code before kicking off the Hive script?

Comment: How your list looks like.? Is it a list just with only one column (industry names) or one of the column in in a table??

Comment: It's a column in a table right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up achieving this using Hive's dynamic partitioning (each partition writes to a separate directory on disk, so I can just iterate through that file). The official [Hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DynamicPartitions) on partitioning and [this](http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.com/2014/11/hive-partitioning.html) blog post were particularly helpful for me.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest go for a shell script..

**Get the list of columns**

> hive -e 'select distinct industry_name from [dbname].[table_name];' > list

**Iterate over every line... passing every line(industry names) of list as argument to the do while loop**

> tail -n +1 list | while IFS=' ' read -r industry_name
>   
> do
>   
>     hive -hiveconf MY_VAR=$industry_name -f my_script.hql
>   
> done

save the shell script as **test.sh**

and in **my_script.hql**

> use uvtest;
>   
> create table ${hiveconf:MY_VAR} (id INT, name CHAR(10));

you'll have to place both the **test.sh** and **my_script.hql** in the same folder.
Below command should create all the tables from list of column names.

> sh test.sh

Follow this link for using hive in shell scripts:
https://www.mapr.com/blog/quick-tips-using-hive-shell-inside-scripts